# Missing block error on nested_form rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nested-forms, nested-attributes

I have some models like

```
class CompanyDepartment < ActiveRecord::Base    
  belongs_to :company

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :phones, :allow_destroy => true
  attr_accessible :phones_attributes
end

class Phone < ActiveRecord::Base  
  has_and_belongs_to_many :companies
  has_and_belongs_to_many :company_departments 
end
```

I'm using **nested_form ryanb** gem. 
All works good when I create **new** company_department.
All phone adding partial works good too.

But when I'm **edit** some company_department, I have error
on phones adding.

It is my phone views:

```
#views/company_departments/_tab_contacts.html.haml
%td
      #phones
        = f.fields_for :phones
        = f.link_to_add "add phone", :phones


#views/company_departments/_phone_fields.html.haml
= f.text_field :number
= f.link_to_remove "delete"
```

Error sounds like

```
 Missing block

 Extracted source (around line #7):

     #views/company_departments/_tab_contacts.html.haml 
     ...
     7:         = f.fields_for :phones
     ...
```

So i'm rendering this tab through ajax.
When i'm rendering without ajax error not shows and all works nice.
But i need to work with ajax :)

Answer (score 1):

Make sure to add a line in your model with the appropriate `accepts\_nested\_attributes\_for`. That's what fixed this for me.

Answer (score 0):

The error message says that you're missing a block for the `fields_for` method.
The code should probably look something like this:

```
#phones
  = f.fields_for :phones do |p|
    = p.link_to_add "add phone", :phones
```

If you look at the [documentation examples for fields for](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper/fields_for), you'll see that block.
You'll also see that block syntax in the [nested_form readme](https://github.com/ryanb/nested_form).

Comment: The [nested_form readme](https://github.com/ryanb/nested_form) contains the variant without a block. And all works good without block when i'm creating new company department object. But when i'm trying to edit existing company department i have got an error with missing block. I think it may be problem with ajax...